# Distribution functions to find missing variable

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, distribution-theory, density-function

**The prompt is to find the values of missing variables over different types of distribution for the same function.**

### $$F(t) = \begin{cases}at^{2} &\mbox{if } t\lt 0\\ bt +c &\mbox{0} \leqslant t \lt 2 \\1 &\mbox{t} \geqslant 2 \end{cases}$$

- (a) the distribution function of a random variable,
- (b) the distribution function of a discrete random variable (find the support of the random variable),
- (c) the distribution function of a continuous random variable (find the density of the random
  variable).

---

**For part a)** I began by considering the properties of a random variable being that

1. The function F(t) is always non-decreasing,
2. F(x) = $\lim_{x\to -\infty} = 0$ and F(x) = $\lim_{x\to \infty} = 1$,
3. F(x) is continuous from the right [i.e., $\lim_{h\to 0^+}F(x+h) = F(x)$ for all x]

Unsure on how to use property 1, I begin by property 2, which is proved automatically as $\lim_{t\to -\infty} at^2 = 0$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty} = 1$. Finally I check the continuity of the function at 0 as follows.

$$\lim_{t\to 0^-}at^2 = \lim_{h\to 0}a(0-h)^2 = 0$$
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}bt+c = \lim_{h\to 0}b(0+h) + c = c$$
Since function is continuous, **c = 0**.

Similarly, finding the limit at 2, 
$$\lim_{t\to 2^-}bt + c = \lim_{h\to 0}b(2-h) + c = 2b + c$$
$$\lim_{t\to 2^+} = 1$$
This gives us 2b + c = 1, since c = 0, $b = \frac{1}{2}$
I'm not sure on how to proceed finding value of a or follow with other parts of the question since they are interdependent.

Comment: what is $F(t)$ doing when $t$ is negative and increasing?

Comment: $F(t) = at^2$ in the case, => $F(t)$ is decreasing.

Comment: So $a$ has to equal what for 1) to hold?

Comment: a must equal 0?